# Run multiple client sites through one Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to run multiple sites through one installation so I only have to update one set of files but users can manage their own content etc.

Would also be interested to hear if it would be possible to limit access so users couldn't install plugins unless I installed them centrally.

Anyone got experience of this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a multisite installation. Take a look: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network